# Can I set the font width of a font in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, phaser-framework

I am using [Phaser 3](https://phaser.io/) to develop a browser game in a canvas with WebGL. I set the width of the canvas text from a **custom loaded** font, but I cannot set it's style (e.g., italic, semibold).

Here is the code that I use to create text:

```js
this.add.text(100, 600, 'Test Text', {
  font: '50px Poppins'
})
this.add.text(100, 600, 'Test Text', {
  font: '50px Poppins semibold'
})
```

Here is the output:

[image]

The second image is using the default font, not Poppins. It seems that as soon as I try to set italic or any other style it will fallback to the default font.

I tried to set it with the properties as well (no luck). Has anyone faced the same issue (styling custom fonts), and how to properly load the styled custom fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the async loading of the fonts from google. With [webfontloader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) from google I can wait with the active event till they are ready.

```js
import WebFont = require('webfontloader')

export class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  private ready: boolean = false
  constructor() {
    super({
      key: 'BootScene'
    })
  }
  async preload(): Promise < any > {
    WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ['Poppins:600i,600,400', 'Inconsolata']
      },
      active: () => {
        // This is required for asnyc loading
        this.ready = true
      }
    })
  }
  // Launch game when all assets are loaded
  update(): void {
    if (this.load.isReady() && this.ready) {
      this.scene.start('MainMenuScene')
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Issue:**

`semibold` is not a valid `font-weight`. so it will be considered as font.

[image]

**Solution:**

[image]

```
this.add.text(100, 600, 'Test Text', {
  font: '600 50px Poppins' // 600 equivalent to Semi Bold
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Comment: Thanks for your idea. However doesn't change anything: https://imgur.com/a/0BxSbRw

Docs also say there is no attribute to set fontWeight: https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.55.2/Phaser.Types.GameObjects.Text.TextStyle

Comment: Thanks for your update. I found the problem. It was not related to the canvas. It was related to the async loading of the fonts from google. With webfontloader from google I can wait with the active event till they are ready. This fixed the issue.

Comment: @LarsFlieger Please consider posting your own answer, and accepting it, since it seems that you had two unrelated issues to address. I'm not sure why you accepted this answer (did it fix one of your problems?), but it's unfortunate that your resolution is buried in a comment.